# How can I import a custom JS in Hybris Backoffice

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I need to import a custom JS in Hybris Backoffice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The following page all the details that you need in order to import your JavaScript into SAP Hybris Backoffice framework:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1811/en-US/cca8e90b37ad4ba3a07154972d2c2576.html